# Noun clause Vs Adjective clause

Tags: difference

I am confused which of the below sentences is correct.

- 1. I know which book Roy sent to me  belongs to Tomy.
- 2. I know the book that Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy.

I think both of these are correct.  The difference is that the first sentence contains a noun clause, the second an adjective clause.  What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: The terms 'noun clause' and 'adjective clause' are misnomers. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech. In 1. "which book Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), and in 2. "that Roy sent to me" is a relative clause modifying "book".

Answer (score 1):

> (a) I know which book Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy.
>
> (b) I know the book that Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy.

Syntax aside, there's a semantic difference between these two. "Which" is selective, which means that it presupposes that there are several options that one can pick. So in (a), it is implied that there is more than one book that Roy sent to you but only one of them belongs to Tomy. In (b), on the other hand, there's no such presupposition. The interpretation is that there's only one book and that book belongs to Tomy.

Syntactically, in (a), "which book Roy sent to me" is **not** a fused-relative construction (also known as a noun clause in traditional grammar); it is a subordinate interrogative. (See [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124273/fused-relatives-versus-interrogatives/124275#124275) on ELU for fused relative vs. subordinate interrogative.) In (b), as you correctly observe, "that Roy sent to me" is a relative clause (also known as an adjective clause in traditional grammar).

Comment: Trad grammar also calls subordinate interrogatives 'noun clauses'.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I know which book Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy.
> 2. I know the book that Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy.

Both examples are grammatical.

In example 1, there is more than one book sent; in example 2, there is only one book sent.

Edit After Bill's Comments

In example 1, "which book Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy" is a subordinate interrogative clause functioning as complement of "know".

The *that-clause* in example 2 is a relative clause modifying *book*.

Comment: No: In 1. "which book Roy sent to me belongs to Tomy" is subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of "know". In 2. it would be better to say that the _that_ clause is a **relative clause**.

Comment: "I know which _of the books that Roy sent to me_ belongs to Tomy" would be better.